# Can I recover a non-system disk deleted during 2008 R2 setup?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hard-drive, partition, data-recovery

I've done a truly stupid thing and 'deleted' the data disk on a Server 2008 R2 box.  Can I recover it?  If so, how?

I was rebuilding the box because a motherboard change had broken things.  I've built loads of boxes and was going through the standard stuff without much concentration.  I got to the disk screen which normally displays the two paritions on the drive: the recovery one and the system one.  As normal, I deleted the two things I saw.  It was only when two lots of unallocated space didn't merge into one that the full horror of what I'd done hit me.  Yes, I've got backups... of the stuff I have space to back up.  The real irony is that, earlier in the day, I'd ordered to 1 TB disks to deal with the problem.

So, anyway, I'd really like to get this partition back because it'll save me a lot of time.  How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the drive in another machine (take an image/clone of the drive if possible) and run data recovery software like R-Studio, GetDataBack NTFS.

If you are not sure how to do this, contact a data recovery company near to you. But always check the company is good first by searching for info about them on web.

Comment: I didn't need to put it in another machine as it was only a data drive.  I used Active@ PartitionRecovery in the end.